# modified CCITT CRC16 algorithm

Tags: c#, vb.net, algorithm, crc, crc16

We have been trying to communicate with a device which uses a modified CCITT CRC16 algorithm. Following was the example defined in the manual

> **`The polynomial for this algorithm is: X**16 + X**12 + X**5 + 1.`**
>
> //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> **at beginning,**
>
> > CRCLSB = 0FFH (octal 377) (decimal 255)
> >
> > CRCMSB = 0FFH (octal 377) (decimal 255)
>
> **then for each data byte in a block,**
>
> > X = D XOR CRCMSB
> >
> > X = X XOR ( X >> 4 )
> >
> > CRCMSB = CRCLSB XOR ( X >> 3 ) XOR ( X << 4 )
> >
> > CRCLSB = X XOR ( X << 5 )
>
> **and at end,**
>
> > CRCLSB = CRCLSB XOR 0FFH
> >
> > CRCMSB = CRCMSB XOR 0FFH
>
> //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

We have a snippet which has been tested

`07
WLAD
ID 123456
PL TEST
PF TEST
BD 1986/01/01
SX M
LN LAB
TS DIFF,1160000109,`

(please see attachment as the data contains special characters)

The Checksum Returned for this data is C9BE.

Could someone please help us with implementing this code in VB.net or C# ?

[data_for_checksum.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgR4qtqLNbJSTVtdTVZX3RCVHM/view?usp=sharing)

**UPDATE**
Apologize for the late response,

We have tried the following in VB.net by adding a textbox and taking the value but getting a long decimal value :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_dec(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim crclsb
    Dim crcmsb
    Dim a As Decimal

    crcmsb = 255
    crclsb = 255
    a = 255
    Dim d As Decimal
    Dim x As Decimal
    For i = 1 To Len(TextBox1.Text)
        'd = Asc(Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1))
        d = Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)
        'd = Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)
        x = d Xor crcmsb
        x = x Xor (x >> 4)
        crcmsb = crclsb Xor (x >> 3) Xor (x << 4)
        crclsb = x Xor (x << 5)



    Next
    'crclsb = Math.Abs(crclsb)
    crclsb = crclsb Xor a
    'crcmsb = Math.Abs(crcmsb)
    crcmsb = crcmsb Xor a
    Dim s
    Dim k
    s = Hex(crclsb)
    k = Hex(crcmsb)


    'C9BE
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim d As Byte
    Dim sstr ' As String

    sstr = TextBox1.Text.ToString
    'sstr = Convert.ToByte(sstr)
    'sstr = Replace(sstr, ", "")
    'crclsb = Convert.ToByte(255)
    'crcmsb = Convert.ToByte(255)
    'crclsb = &HFF
    'crcmsb = &HFF
    For i = 1 To Len(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim a As Byte
        a = Asc(Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1))
        d = Convert.ToByte(a)

        Call calc_crc(d)


    Next
    'Call calc_crc(sstr)
    Debug.Print(crcmsb)
    Debug.Print(crclsb)
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet or just asking for someone to do it for you?

Comment: FYI, that is not the CCITT CRC-16.  It is referred to in the CRC catalogue at [CRC-16/GENIBUS](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-genibus).  I implemented it and verified that it computes the CRC correctly.  It uses a clever set of exclusive-ors to avoid a large stored table.  I do not plan to share the implementation with you, since you really need to give it a shot yourself.

Comment: Dear Alex & Mark, we had tried ourselves but couldn't achieve desired results hence posted on stackoverflow. We have updated the post with the code. Please let us know if you require any more information & thanks for your assistance.